# python's tar module and behavior of exclude method

Tags: python, tar

I need to force python's tar module to work as tar command in shell and the problem is in "exclude" method.

**Example of tar in shell**(and it works as designed, we added exclude and nginx.conf was excluded from archive):

```
xasan@dell [python]$ find /etc/nginx/* -iname 'nginx.conf'
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

xasan@dell [python]$ tar czvf /tmp/test.tar.gz --exclude nginx.conf 
/etc/nginx/proxy_params 
/etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf 
/etc/nginx/mime.types 
/etc/nginx/win-utf 
/etc/nginx/koi-win 
/etc/nginx/sites-available/ 
/etc/nginx/sites-available/default 
/etc/nginx/koi-utf 
/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params 
/etc/nginx/uwsgi_params 
/etc/nginx/snippets/ 
/etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf 
/etc/nginx/snippets/snakeoil.conf 
/etc/nginx/scgi_params 
/etc/nginx/conf.d/ 
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ 
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

xasan@dell [python]$ tar tzvf /tmp/test.tar.gz | grep 'nginx.conf$'
xasan@dell [python]$
```

**Let's do the same with python module:**

```
import tarfile                                                                                                               

excl='nginx.conf'                                                                                                            
what='/etc/nginx'                                                                                                       

tar=tarfile.open('/tmp/test.tar.gz','w:gz')                                                                                  

tar.add(what,exclude=lambda x: True if what in excl else False)                                                              
tar.close()
```

Checking. And we can see that exclude doesn't work as in native tar

```
xasan@dell [python]$ tar tzf /tmp/test.tar.gz | grep -i 'nginx.conf$'
etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

I've experimented with getting all data in directory which I want to archive and then use full-path names of excluded objects... it works, but it's inconvenient.

Something like that:

```
import tarfile                                                                                                               
import os 

excl='nginx.conf'                                                                                                            
what='/etc/nginx'
lst_of_dirs_1lvl=os.listdir(what) # list of content in the 1st level of  dir 

tar=tarfile.open('/tmp/test.tar.gz','w:gz')                                                                                  

for i in lst_of_dirs_1lvl:                                                                                                   
    full_path_obj='{0}/{1}'.format(what,i) # full path to the object which we're adding to archive                                                                             
    tar.add(full_path_obj,exclude=lambda x: True if i in excl else False)                                                    
tar.close()
```

There is no our excluded file in archive, so it works:

```
xasan@dell [python]$ tar tzf /tmp/test.tar.gz | grep -i 'nginx.conf$'
xasan@dell [python]$
```

But in this case we can exclude only objects in the first nesting level, so we need to build tree of files in archived dir and then run inside that tree ... so it's not a good solution.

Comment: `True if what in excl else False` - `what` is `'/etc/nginx'` and `excl` is `'nginx.conf'`. It's no surprise that `what` is never a substring of `excl`.

Comment: It's not an answer, I see it. The question is - how to get the behavior like shell tar command, when you don't need to specify every file in directory which you want to archive. You just simply specify /etc/nginx and exclude statement and tar knows that it needs to run recursively inside /etc/nginx and to compare each element with exclude.